# Python flask: return values multiple times

Tags: python, flask

I ran my code on Jupyter Notebook and I wanted to return different values on the web while running the function. However, it only returned one value. I also tried **yield**, but it had an error on the web.

```
from werkzeug.wrappers import Request, Response
from flask import Flask


app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/') 
def index():
    list = [0,0,0]
    for i in range(10):
        list.append(i)
        return str(list)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    from werkzeug.serving import run_simple
    run_simple('localhost', 9000, app)
```

Output:
*[0,0,0,0]*

Expected Output: 
*[0,0,0,0]*
then change to:
*[0,0,0,0,1]*
then go on until it stops at:
*[0,0,0,0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]*

Comment: You haven't finished looping through your list yet. Untab your return statement. You do mention 9 though, so is the append function the right tool you're looking for though?

Comment: @zenalc it's more like I will set a time sleep for one second between every loop. So on the web it will show [0,0,0,0] first, then it will jump to [0,0,0,0,1] after one second and continue on. Just edit my code, I get your point now :)

Comment: You need Ajax. Otherwise after you untab the return, only the last output will be displayed.

Comment: Yep, you'll need AJAX. Flask won't be able to update it interactively without a refresh AFAIK.

Answer (score -1):

Your indent is a little off on the return of the list.  This is returning it on the first loop.  Corrected Code is below:

```
from werkzeug.wrappers import Request, Response
from flask import Flask


app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/') 
def index():
    list = [0,0,0]
    for i in range(10):
        list.append(i)
    return str(list)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    from werkzeug.serving import run_simple
    run_simple('localhost', 9000, app)
```

Comment: Hi! Your code will only print the last output, but I was trying to let it look like the number is appending on the web :)

Comment: I don't think this is possible from Flask,  you would need some sort of AJAX script.